# Bind Property of a Class in a List from an ObservableCollection to a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I just started a new project and used this occasion to get used to MVVM.

But I am faltering with a special case, where I try to bind a list of a custom class from my ObservableCollection to a Datagrid.
I use the following constellation and all I can accomplish is the Datagrid Column showing a Collection.
https://snag.gy/2MDEuS.jpg

If I try to advance further into the Object with {Binding Path=Supplier.Supplier} it aint working with the following error which indicates, the compiler is not able to read the property from the list, as I interpret the error:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : 
    BindingExpression path error: 
    'Supplier' property not found on 'object' ''List`1' (HashCode=55391087)'. 
    BindingExpression:Path=Supplier.Supplier; 
    DataItem='O_SupplierReport' (HashCode=61342683); 
    target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); 
    target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

There are other textboxes, I can easily fill with Binding={Binding Path=MySelectedItem.SupplierName} for example.
Can you give me an advice on this?

```
//ViewModel
public class V_SupplierReport: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<O_SupplierReport> _SupplierReports;
        public O_SupplierReport MySelectedItem { get; set; }
        private List<S_Supplier> _Supplier { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (!(PropertyChanged == null))
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
        public ObservableCollection<O_SupplierReport> SupplierReports
        {
            get { return _SupplierReports; }
            set { _SupplierReports = value; }
        }
        public V_SupplierReport()
        {
            this._SupplierReports = new ObservableCollection<O_SupplierReport>();
        }
        public int Lieferanten
        {
            get { return _Supplier; }
            set
            {
                if (_Supplier == value) return;
                _Supplier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Supplier");
            }
        }
    }

//Model
public class O_SupplierReport : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<S_Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }

        public O_SupplierReport(List<S_Supplier> sup)
        {
            this.Supplier = sup;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (!(PropertyChanged == null))
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

//Classpublic class S_Supplier
    {
        public int Supplier { get; set; } 
        public S_Supplier(int sup) 
        { 
            Supplier = sup; 
        } 
    }

    //View
<Window x:Class="APP.SDX.SupplierReports.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="483.8" Width="640" DataContext="{Binding SupplierReports}">
     <Grid>
         <DataGrid Name="G_lb_Selektion_Lieferanten" 
                            Margin="0,26,0,27" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SupplierReports}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
             <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lieferant" Binding="{Binding Supplier}" />
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lieferant" Binding="{Binding Path=Supplier}" />
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lieferant" Binding="{Binding Path=Supplier.Supplier}" />
             </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Additional to the answer I found a more fitting solution without the need of a DataGridTemplateColumn:
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem.Supplier}" DisplayMemberPath="Supplier" in the view did the trick too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGridTextColumn` can only display the value of a scalar property of the type `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` ItemsSource of the `DataGrid`.

If you want to display all `S_Supplier` objects inside the "Lieferant" column you could use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a nested `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="G_lb_Selektion_Lieferanten" 
                            Margin="0,26,0,27" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SupplierReports}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lieferant" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Supplier}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If there is only one `S_Supplier` object in the `List<S_Supplier>` and you want to display a property of this one you could bind to the first item in the list using an indexer:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Lieferant" Binding="{Binding Supplier[0].Supplier }" />
```

Comment: Sir, you are awesome!